# vertex naming is not working in tikz-feynman

Tags: tikz-feynman

I want to name the left and right hand vertex x and y.but it is not working.

```
\usepackage{tikz-feynman}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman} 
\usepackage{simpler-wick}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
   a[dot]--[fermion,half left,edge label=\(p_1\)]b[dot],a--[fermion,half right,edge label'=\(p_2\)]b[dot],
   a--[out=135,in=-135,loop,min distance=2cm,anti fermion,edge label'=\(p_3\)]a,
   b--[fermion,out=45,in=-45,loop,min distance=2cm,edge label=\(p_4\)]b
    };

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
 a[particle=\(x\)]--[fermion,half left,edge label=\(p_1\)]b[particle=\(y\)],a--[fermion,half right,edge label'=\(p_2\)]b[dot],
   a--[out=135,in=-135,loop,min distance=2cm,anti fermion,edge label'=\(p_3\)]a,
   b--[fermion,out=45,in=-45,loop,min distance=2cm,edge label=\(p_4\)]b
    };
\end{document}
```

these codes generate this result. but I cant have both.how i can do that 2 in 1?
thank you. :)

[image]

Comment: how to edit? my  posts are completely not understandable until editing.how to do that?

Comment: Select the code, then click the button marked `{}` above the text field (or use the keyboard shortcut Ctrl + K).

Comment: Can you turn your snippet into a complete, compilable example? (Including documentclass, the necessary packages and definitions.) You also seem to have forgotten a `\feynmandiagram[...` line.

Comment: oh yes.sorry. my bad.i just wrote the inner code without the header files.thanks

Comment: there there,i edited myself..:D.thank you for your kind help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A vertex cannot be both `particle` and `dot`, but you can add a label next to a dot, with `dot,label=right:text`.

Note also that when you have defined `b` once, then using `b[dot]` when you draw a line from `a` to `b` throws an error. Therefore I removed `[dot]` two places in your code, indicated by comments.

[image: output of code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}
\begin{document}
\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
 a[particle=\(x\)]--[fermion,half left,edge label=\(p_1\)]
 b[particle=\(y\)],
   a--[fermion,half right,edge label'=\(p_2\)] b, % removed [dot] after b here
   a--[out=135,in=-135,loop,min distance=2cm,anti fermion,edge label'=\(p_3\)]a,
   b--[fermion,out=45,in=-45,loop,min distance=2cm,edge label=\(p_4\)]b
 };

\feynmandiagram[horizontal=a to b, layered layout]{
   a[dot,label=right:\(x\)] % added label=right:\(x\)
    --[fermion,half left,edge label=\(p_1\)]
    b[dot,label=left:\(y\)], % similarly here
   a --[fermion,half right,edge label'=\(p_2\)] b, % removed [dot] after b here as well
   a --[out=135,in=-135,loop,min distance=2cm,anti fermion,edge label'=\(p_3\)] a,
   b --[fermion,out=45,in=-45,loop,min distance=2cm,edge label=\(p_4\)] b
    };

\end{document}
```